# When I am trying to upload my data to firebase it is not uploading?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am working on an app and I am trying to add my images to the storage and image URL in the real-time database but when I m trying to upload it is saying failed. I am not able to understand why it is happening. please look into it and guide me on why it is happening. I am new to android so it is a little but difficult for me to understand things. please look into it. thank you

Main Activity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//widgets
private Button uploadBtn;
private ImageView imageView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;


private DatabaseReference databasereference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Image");
private StorageReference storagereference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
private Uri imageUri;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    uploadBtn = findViewById(R.id.fabUploadImage);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.no_image);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent , 2);
        }
    });

    uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (imageUri != null){
                uploadToFirebase(imageUri);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Select Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode ==2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

    }
}

private void uploadToFirebase(Uri uri){

    final StorageReference fileRef = storagereference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(uri));
    fileRef.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                    Model model = new Model(uri.toString());
                    String modelId = databasereference.push().getKey();
                    databasereference.child(modelId).setValue(model);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_iamge);
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploading Failed !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private String getFileExtension(Uri mUri){

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(mUri));

}
```

}

My Model Class

```
public class Model {

private String imageUrl;

public Model()
{

}

public Model(String imageUrl)
{
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```

}

Comment: "but when I m trying to upload it is saying failed" => What **exact** error message do you get?

Comment: yes it is saying falied showing the toast in the onfailure method

Comment: But what says the exception?? `public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {...}`? If you don't print the exception messages in your code you cannot debug it... and nobody can help you because neither you nor us know what's happening.... You can do something like `System.out.println("onFailure: " + e.getMessage());`

Comment: sir in my case no exception or error is occurring but only  addOnFailureListener method is running and the toast showing..

Comment: Did you add the last line from my above comment in the `onFailure()` block?

Comment: yes sir i have added them

Comment: it is saying sir that user does not have permission to access this object

Comment: So have you set the proper rules?

Comment: where sir sorry??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered after debugging your code, you should set the permissions to allow uploading objects to the Cloud Storage bucket attached to your project.

You should read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) and adapt the security rules, according to your access rights strategy.

---

Note that it may be interesting, **in a test environment**, to temporarily allow write access to everybody in order to check that your android code is correct (i.e. it correctly upload files). For that you would use the following rules.

```
service firebase.storage {
  // The {bucket} wildcard indicates we match files in all Cloud Storage buckets
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Match filename
    match /filename {
      allow read: if ...;
      allow write: if true;  // Allow uploading for everybody
    }
  }
}
```

Again, do not use such rules in a **production environment**: They allow everybody to write to your bucket! Unless you app is made to allow every unauthenticated user to upload files...

Comment: Done sir thank you so much..for your great help sir.